# In WPF, how can I make ToolBar.Header disappear?

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I have read in two different books that in WPF, the ToolBar.Header property doesn't do anything:

- Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed by Adam Nathan, pg. 119
- [Pro WPF with VB 2008, pg. 650](http://books.google.ca/books?id=3UqXw90ju5IC&pg=PA650&lpg=PA650&dq=toolbar+header+wpf&source=bl&ots=SSmU69Ysh4&sig=JRqqrhJH5GIuCu7QYe24dQhdhGo&hl=en&ei=xnMRSpv5GpfEMtvl7KYG&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10)

However, I'm creating my ToolBar objects dynamically like this (tbtToolBar is actually a ToolBarTray defined in the Xaml, vm is the window's ViewModel):

```
foreach (IToolBarViewModel toolBarViewModel in vm.ToolBars)
{
    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar();
    toolBar.DataContext = toolBarViewModel;

    // Bind the Header Property
    Binding headerBinding = new Binding("Header");
    toolBar.SetBinding(ToolBar.HeaderProperty, headerBinding);

    // Bind the Items Property
    Binding itemsBinding = new Binding("Items");
    toolBar.SetBinding(ToolBar.ItemsSourceProperty, itemsBinding);

    tbtToolBar.ToolBars.Add(toolBar);
}
```

And the Header property clearly shows up in a label as the first item in the toolbar.  This is not the behavior I want.  I would like to use the Header as a title in a drop-down list of ToolBars when the user right clicks on the ToolBarTray, just like the books describe.

So, I tried to get rid of the Header by setting:

```
toolBar.HeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate();
```

This works, but now there's a small unsightly gap in the toolbar.

1. Is there a way to make the header invisible without the gap?
2. Why are the books clearly wrong?  Did something change between then and now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to make this work was to keep the Header property null, and create another property on the ToolBarViewModel called Name.